# What does ^ mean in PHP?

Tags: php

I came across this line of code in an application I am revising:

```
substr($sometext1 ^ $sometext2, 0, 512);
```

What does the `^` mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [bitwise operator](http://phpbuilder.com/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Example:

```
"hallo" ^ "hello"
```

It outputs the ASCII values `#0` `#4` `#0` `#0` `#0` (`'a'` ^ `'e'` = `#4`).

Comment: im having tough time understanding about the ascii values, if we take a and e as binary equivalents like so:
a=01100101
e=01100001
---------
xor=00000100

is this right?

Answer (score 8):

`^` is the bitwise exclusive OR operator. For each bit in a value, it looks to see if that bit is the same in the other value; if it is the same, a 0 is output in its place, otherwise a 1 is output. For example:

```
  00001111
^ 01010101
  --------
  01011010
```

Comment: How does that work on strings? (re [Michael Borgwardt's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724936/what-does-mean-in-php/2724974#2724974))

Answer (score 7):

[XOR (exclusive OR)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php):

> $a ^ $b means bits that are set in $a or $b, but not both, are set.

Answer (score 2):

It's the [XOR (exclusive-or) operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR).  For strings it's used as [simple encryption](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/xor-encryption.htm).

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, `^` means 'bitwise XOR'. Your code XORs together two strings, then returns at most the first 512 characters.

In other words it does this:

```
return (at most the first 512 characters of (someText1 XOR someText2))
```

Comment: @webdestroya: 512, of course :) - it was a typo; thanks. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

That's the [bitwise OR operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) - in PHP, it also applies to strings.

Answer (score 0):

`^` matches the starting position within the string. In line-based tools, it matches the starting position of any line.

Comment: that would be a regular expression

Comment: which it would do since the first character that does not match is now XOR'd and will show up as a 1.  I guess it would depend on what the original code was trying to accomplish - based on this example of "what does this do" .. we would of course need to know more information - as opposed to "what does this "^" character do.