# Php, calculating exponent with caret (^) fails

Tags: php, exponent

Wolfram Alpha says will give the correct result for the following formula:

```
((0.0004954*($current^2))-((0.935*$current)+378.486))-
((0.0004954*($desired^2))-((0.935*$desired)+378.486));
```

But when I run it in PHP, it does not give the correct answer, why not?

```
$current = mysql_escape_string($_POST['current']);
$desired = mysql_escape_string($_POST['desired']);
$username = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$email = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$time = time();
$elo = $desired - $current;
if($current < 1200) {
  $price = ($elo/100)*30;
} elseif($current < 1400) {
  $price = ($elo/100)*35;
} elseif($current < 1901) {
  $price = ((0.0004954*($current^2))-((0.935*$current)+378.486))-((0.0004954*($desired^2))-((0.935*$desired)+378.486));
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The `^` operator is a [bitwise](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) operator.

You need to use [pow](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php).

If you just want to square a value, then you can just multiple it by itself, `$current * $current`.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the `pow($number, $exponent)` function.

In PHP, the `^` [doesn't mean an exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724936/what-does-mean-in-php).

`$price = ((0.0004954*(pow($current, 2)))-((0.935*$current)+378.486))-((0.0004954*              (pow($desired, 2)))-((0.935*$desired)+378.486));`

Answer (score 4):

^ is the XOR bitwise operator

You can use pow as mentioned by Supericy, but you can also just use the ** operator for shorthand.