# Why result is always integer?

Tags: php

I have the weirdest thing in PHP.

I have a function like this:

```
function Calculate_i_from_IDF($coef, $Tc)
{
    print_r($coef);
    $intensity=$coef[0]+$coef[1]*$Tc+$coef[2]*$Tc^2+$coef[3]*$Tc^3+$coef[4]*$Tc^4;
    echo "intensity=$intensity<P>";
    return $intensity;
}
```

My Tc=1.  The result is:

> Array ( [0] => 1.1413387743 [1] => -0.7177898193 [2] => 0.6190050656
>   [3] => -0.4272211298 [4] => 0.0813729821 )
>
> intensity=7

What I don't understand is why `$intensity` is 7 instead of the expected 0.696706.  It is so weird!  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Frank

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php, calculating exponent with carrot (^) fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371386/php-calculating-exponent-with-carrot-fails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` is not the exponent operator, but a bitwise operator.  That is likely causing the expression to result in an integer.  Try [using `pow`](http://php.net/pow).

Related: [Php, calculating exponent with carrot (^) fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371386/php-calculating-exponent-with-carrot-fails)

Comment: Wow.  It is that simple!  Thank you so much!  You saved my day.

Comment: @Frank, I'm glad to hear it.  If that solved your problem, you can accept it as an answer by clicking the green checkmark.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Frank . please accept it as an answer. So many people get the answer/help  they're looking for and fail to acknowledge the individual who helped them.