# Why is the output Negative?

Tags: php, math, webserver

Perhaps I am incredibly stupid, but I have no idea why the output is negative?

It is really affecting my program

```
<?php

$vone =  10833087074.438;


$massone = 1;
$keone = $vone ^ 2;

echo $keone;
echo "<BR>";
$keone = $keone * $massone;
echo $keone;
echo "<BR>";
$keone = .5 * $keone;

echo $keone;

?>
```

Comment: What is your output values?

Comment: What would you *expect*? I suppose you think `^` means "power of"? (Hint: wrong)

Comment: What you are expecting in output???

Comment: Thank you for the response, noob mistake I guess I am stupid what is "^" and how do I do exponent instead?

Comment: @Orca [bitwise xor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724936/what-does-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Many notations use "^" as a power operator, but in PHP (and other C-based languages) that is actually the XOR operator. You need to use this 'pow' function, there is no power operator.

In your code

```
$keone = $vone ^ 2;
```

Should be

```
$keone = pow($vone,2);
```

Rest of your code is fine. That **[pow](https://www.php.net/pow)** function is the one you should use to raise your baise to the power given.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<?php

$vone =  10833087074.438;


$massone = 1;
$keone = pow($vone,2);

echo $keone;
echo "<BR>";
$keone = $keone * $massone;
echo $keone;
echo "<BR>";
$keone = .5 * $keone;

echo $keone;

?>
```